# Easily assign Reducing Vertex Weights?

Tags: vertices, weight-painting

/

Hi. I want to assign **Vertex Weight** in Vertex Groups in a reducing fashion. Is there a quick way to do it instead of selecting every vertex group every time and assigning them the desired Weights? I tried *Gradient in Weight Paint* but unable to control it and distribute weights evenly. Please help.

_
[image]